# 'su root' succeeded for root on /dev/??? - SunOS logging

Tags: linux, unix, logging, solaris

I have a log like this in */var/log/authlog* :

```
<date> <server> su: [ID 366847 auth.notice] 'su root' succeeded for root on /dev/???
```

and in /var/adm/sulog

```
SU 12/12 11:13 + ??? root-root
```

It is repeated every 2 minutes, but there is no scheduled job active for this purpose.

1) What's the meaning of **/dev/???** , why these '**???**'?

2) How can i see if a process (if this is) is doing this action every 2 minutes ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It’s probably trying to tell you what terminal it happened on — this is a holdover from the days of physical terminals that were in fixed locations, so if you saw `/dev/tty42`, you might know “that’s in room 217” and you could go and look who it was.  `/dev/???` probably means that a call to `ttyname()` failed, so it’s a detached process (which, I expect, you had already guessed). `'su root' succeeded for root` probably means that the process is *already* root, and is running `'su root'` for some unknown reason — so, in a sense, it may be harmless. Sorry I don’t have a real answer.

Comment: What's in root's crontab?

Comment: Thanxs @G-Man ... good hint ttryname() that i didn't know ...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Anything that run every 2 minutes (i'm sure). I was thinking about a process running as root, that tries the 'su root', the problem is that i don't know how to find this process (there are so many as root, is not my machine), that also fails the call to ttyname() .. i will go more in deep with this ttyname() .. if you have some suggestions how i can troublehsoot this problem will be helpful :)